# Understanding why ports need to be exposed for inter container communication on docker0

Tags: docker, containers

I was going through docker official docs to understand the difference between user-defined and default bridge. Link to specific page - https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

In first point of section "**Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge**", it is stated that

> If you run the same application stack on the default bridge network,
>   you need to open both the web port and the database port, using the -p
>   or --publish flag for each.

I don't understand this specific text, as to why it is need to explicitly publish(-p) required port of database container when it will be used only by some other container connected to the same bridge. 
My existing understanding is that, unless explicitly blocked, containers connected to the docker0 can freely communicate with each other.

So, this extract has confused me. Can somebody help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take away one thing from that page, it's that you should always `docker create network` and then `docker run --net` containers on that network, if you're using plain Docker commands.  (Docker Compose does this automatically for you; Kubernetes's networking model is fundamentally different.)

If you `docker run` a container without a `--net` option then you wind up using a backwards-compatiblitiy networking mode.  In this mode (the "default bridge network") from the page you cite containers *cannot* communicate with each other by default.  Your two options are for the server to publish a port (`docker run -p`) and the client to connect to the published port on the host, or for the server to expose a port (almost always done with an `EXPOSE` directive in the Dockerfile) and the client to `--link` to it.

There's no real reason to be using this "default" mode at this point, and in practice the paragraph you cite shouldn't matter except for fairly old scripted Docker setups.

Comment: "containers cannot communicate with each other by default". How is this true ? isn't the default value of -icc=true guaranteeing it for the bridged containers on same host ?

Comment: Two paragraphs below what you quoted: "Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the `--link` option...."  But, the container-private IP addresses are not at all stable, and it's kind of hard to find them.  There is in fact not a "hard" isolation between containers, you're right.

Comment: Yes.. that's was I was talking about - not completely isolated but as you described it's also true that its hard finding the other container's ip address and not the right way. Since, i only wanted my understanding to be validated.. marking the question as resolved :)